# wpf dispatcher error in tag property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an error accessing a WPF element in code behind (see indicated error line):

```
Thumb sThumb = new Thumb();
...

TextBox Thumbtxt = (TextBox)sThumb.Template.FindName("TextThumb", sThumb);

if (Thumbtxt.Tag != null) <-- Unhandled Exception: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
{
    if (Thumbtxt.Tag.ToString() == "Disabled")
        IsDisabled = true;
}
```

I then tried to execute the code in the dispatcher, as follows:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
{
    Thumb sThumb = new Thumb();
    ...

    TextBox Thumbtxt = (TextBox)sThumb.Template.FindName("TextThumb", sThumb);

    if (Thumbtxt.Tag != null)
    {
        if (Thumbtxt.Tag.ToString() == "Disabled")
            IsDisabled = true;    
}));
```

Still, I get the same error in the very same line. I use this dispatcher invoke in other parts and it works fine, but apparently it doesn't like the "Tag" property, for some reason.

Can someone please shed some light?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

```
  await Task.Run(() => { TextBox Thumbtxt = (TextBox)sThumb.Template.FindName("TextThumb", sThumb); })
.ContinueWith(
                                   res =>
                                   {
                                       you code here 
                                   },
                                       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the dispatcher that is associated with the Thumbtxt control:

```
        Thumbtxt.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> 
        {
            if (Thumbtxt.Tag != null)
            {
                if (Thumbtxt.Tag.ToString() == "Disabled")
                    IsDisabled = true;
            };
        }));
```

Comment: I tried this code but the app is now freezing on this line. Thanks for trying though. Regards

Comment: Then you are doing something strange. Make sure that you create ALL controls on a single thread, i.e. the dispatcher thread that your application starts on.